How to connect esp-cam with Arduinoide?
I want to connect ESP-CAM with my PC and doesn't work.
I connect the ESP-CAM with my PC and upload the code in ARDUINO IDE in the monitor serial nothing appear, and when I press in RST button, it's appear this message "ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download"
Such that the code is compiled, and uploaded to the ESP-CAM (ESP-CAM with USB which means is connected directly to PC without FTDI), just nothing appeared in SErial monitor.
Can anyone tell me please what should I do?
